# node.js + jQuery,ajax send array or json to server, payload too large.

Tags: jquery, node.js

for example:
jQuery:

```
var sendTemp=[];
var t={
   string:'this is test string1',
   time: '2017-03-20T04:25:06.584Z',
   type:'file',
   location:'usa',
   broken:false,
}
```

I test the `var max` value array to send server,
when `max` > 500~600 server return error message `payload too large problem`.

```
var max=600;
for(var i=0;i<max;i++){
    sendTemp.push(t);
}
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url:"/send",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
        sendTemp:JSON.stringify(sendTemp),
    },
    success:function(data){

    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

    }
});
```

I found a solution but did not work,in app.js

node.js:

set limit:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

set port:

```
 app.post('/send',function(req, res, next){  
      console.log(req.body);
      res.end();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue. I did ajax post and got 413 payload too large error.
By checking net and documentation I solved this problem by setting limit directly to body-parser.

`app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));`

I hope this will be useful.